# How to write in container field table from code?

Tags: containers, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a simple question, I have in my Table a Field.
This field is type **container** .

How I can write in this field.

I used this code, but don't work:

```
MyTable myTable;
str value = "value" ;
ttsBegin;
select forupdate myTable;
conIns( myTable.FieldContainet, 1 , value );
myTable.insert();
ttsCommit ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Containers are immutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa874816.aspx), you therefore have to assign the result of `conIns` to your container field:

```
myTable.FieldContainet = conIns(myTable.FieldContainet, 1, value);
```

Try to use `myTable.FieldContainet += value;` instead, it is easier to read and performs better.

Second method, if exist container initialized value:

```
container con;
con = ["valueI" , "valueII" , "valueIII"];
//other code
myTable.FieldContainet = con;
```

Copy all the values contained in **container**.